# Вопрос про bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Есть ноутбуки с 13-14дюймами и разрешением 1920x1080, на них сайт смотрится криво, какое это примерное разрешение?

Comment: переформулируйте пожалуйста вопрос, он не совсем понятен.

Comment: в общем так на разрешении 1920х1080 на обычном мониторе у меня отображается сайт так как надо, а если зайти с ноутбука с 13-14" монитором и с таким разрешением то показывает как будто разрешение очень маленькое

Comment: там плотность пикселей побольше будет. И если в коде есть привязка к размеру в пикселях, то да, будет перекос.

Comment: как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть полезным - в Google Chrome вы сами можете эмулировать разрешения мониторов https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode

Также можете и в живую посмотреть здесь, выбрав нужные ОС и разрешение монитора http://www.browserstack.com/

Собственно благодаря этим средствам вы и сможете понять, на каких разрешениях начинает всё ехать

---

PS: а простые ресайз или масштабирование не помогают? :)

Comment: Информативный ответ, голосую)

Comment: вся проблема в том что у меня нет под рукой этого ноутбука)))

Comment: @reddyk, пройдите по второй ссылке, и у вас будет то разрешение, которое захотите. \\

Грубо говоря - вам дадут удалённое управление на нужную ОС/браузер/разрешение монитора